# Ansible through Bastion server SSH Error

Tags: ssh, proxy, ansible, ansible-2.x

Following this guide (and others) [running-ansible-through-ssh-bastion-host](http://blog.scottlowe.org/2015/12/24/running-ansible-through-ssh-bastion-host/).
I have my ssh.cfg file set up to allow connecting to a host behind multiple bastions.

proxy -> util -> monitor -> more

I can connect to the util server:

`[self@home]$ ssh -F ssh.cfg util
...
[self@util]$`

and the monitoring server:

`[self@home]$ ssh -F ssh.cfg monitor
...
[self@monitor]$`

ssh.conf:

```
Host *
    ServerAliveInterval 60
    ControlMaster   auto
    ControlPath     ~/.ssh/mux-%r@%h:%p
    ControlPersist  15m

Host proxy
    HostName proxy01.com
    ForwardAgent yes

Host util
    HostName util01.priv
    ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p proxy

Host monitor
    HostName mon01.priv
    ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p util
```

ansible inventory file:

```
[bastion]
    proxy

[utility]
    util
    monitor
```

ansible.cfg:

```
[ssh_connection]
ssh_args = -F ./ssh.cfg -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=15m
control_path = ~/.ssh/ansible-%%r@%%h:%%p
```

When I execute any ansible commands, they appear to hit the proxy host without any problem, but fail to connect to the util host and the monitor host.

```
> ansible all -a "/bin/echo hello"
util | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "msg": "SSH Error: data could not be sent to the remote host. Make sure this host can be reached over ssh", 
    "unreachable": true
}
proxy | SUCCESS | rc=0 >>
hello

monitor | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh.", 
    "unreachable": true
}
```

ADDITIONAL:
after some more hacking around, I have key'd the monitor host, and found that ansible can connect to the proxy,and the monitor, but fails on the util host... which is extremely odd because it has to pass through the util host to hit the monitor.

```
util | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "msg": "SSH Error: data could not be sent to the remote host. Make sure this host can be reached over ssh", 
    "unreachable": true
}
proxy | SUCCESS | rc=0 >>
hello
monitor | SUCCESS | rc=0 >>
hello
```

Answer (score 1):

After trying different guides, this solution work for me to use the ansible over the server that doesn't have directory ssh but via proxy/bastion.

Here is my ~/.ssh/config file:

```
Host *
    ServerAliveInterval 60
    StrictHostKeyChecking no
    UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
    ForwardAgent yes

####### Access to the Private Subnet Server through Proxy/bastion ########

Host proxy-server
    HostName x.x.x.x
    ForwardAgent yes

Host private-server
  HostName y.y.y.y
  ProxyCommand ssh -q proxy-server nc -q0 %h %p
```

Hope that help you.

Comment: I tried using 'ProxyCommand ssh -q proxy nc -q0 %h %p', for my util host, which gives me:
util | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh.", 
    "unreachable": true
}
using 'ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p proxy' returned:
util | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "msg": "SSH Error: data could not be sent to the remote host. Make sure this host can be reached over ssh", 
    "unreachable": true
}

Comment: can you ssh to it without mentioning the `-F`

Comment: Yes, I can connect to it manually, or using my regular ssh/config file without a problem

Comment: can you share the `ssh` command that you use to connect to the remote host through the bastion/proxy

Answer (score 0):

For some unknown reason Ansible ignores multiple hosts, following config helped me

```
Host 10.*
  StrictHostKeyChecking no
  GSSAPIAuthentication no
  ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p -l ubuntu -i ~/.ssh/key.pem 11.22.33.44
  ControlMaster auto
  ControlPersist 15m
  User ubuntu
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/key.pem
```